error "Fail to join data" for sagemaker batch transform with BatchStrategy="MultiRecord"
I'm trying to run Sagemaker Transform job with the following configuration:
BatchStrategy="MultiRecord" and "JoinSource": "Input" 

using the - content-type='text/csv' and accept='text/csv'
However I'm getting an error
[sagemaker logs]: my-path-to-s3/batch/input/sample_batch_transform_payload.csv: 
Fail to join data: mismatched line count between the input and the output

When I run the code with

BatchStrategy="SingleRecord"

everything works.
My model outputs are embeddings of 1024 so
the predictions are similar to the below array (assuming that my input csv had 3 rows)
import numpy as np
predictions = np.array([
             np.random.randn(1024),
             np.random.randn(1024),
             np.random.randn(1024)
         ])
print(predictions.shape)
# (3, 1024)

I've tried various outputs for the output_fn function but all failed with the same above error
Here is how AWS sagemaker-inference toolkit implements the output but I still get the same error
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
def output_fn(predictions, accept="text/csv"):
  stream = StringIO() 
  np.savetxt(stream, predictions, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
  csv_output = stream.getvalue()

  return csv_output

Here is the configuration of the Transform job:
{
 'TransformJobName': 'ai-manual-transform-job-2024-05-28T10-35-50',
 'TransformJobArn': '<MY-ARN>',
 'TransformJobStatus': 'Failed',
 'FailureReason': 'ClientError: See job logs for more information',
 'ModelName': '<MY-MODEL>',
 'MaxConcurrentTransforms': 1,
 'MaxPayloadInMB': 6,
 'BatchStrategy': 'MultiRecord',
 'TransformInput': {'DataSource': {'S3DataSource': {'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
    'S3Uri': '<PATH-To-S3>'}},
  'ContentType': 'text/csv',
  'CompressionType': 'None',
  'SplitType': 'Line'},
 'TransformOutput': {'S3OutputPath': '<PATH-to-s3-output>',
  'Accept': 'text/csv',
  'AssembleWith': 'Line',
  'KmsKeyId': ''},
 'TransformResources': {'InstanceType': 'ml.m5.large', 'InstanceCount': 1},
 'CreationTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 28, 10, 35, 51, 145000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'TransformStartTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 28, 10, 39, 35, 16000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'TransformEndTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 28, 10, 42, 32, 743000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'DataProcessing': {'InputFilter': '$[4]',
  'OutputFilter': '$',
  'JoinSource': 'Input'},

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Update
when running the following code
def output_fn(predictions, accept="text/csv"):
  stream = StringIO() 
  np.savetxt(stream, predictions, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
  csv_output = stream.getvalue()

  return csv_output, accept

I get a different error
[sagemaker logs]: [sagemaker logs]: my-path-to-s3/batch/input/sample_batch_transform_payload.csv:
Failed to parse output from the algorithm as CSV: 
bare " in non quoted field found near: ["-0.07831139862537384


I would recommend you opening a support case for the SageMaker team to look at the backend logs
